# defining a struct

Tags: c++, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

what is the difference between:

```
struct a{
...
}
```

and

```
typedef struct{
...
}  a;
```

?

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Comment: I don't think there is one (both define a type named `a`), but the first is simpler and more idiomatic. You sometimes see the second version in C code where the first version defines a type that has to be referred as `struct a` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, there is no difference.  In C, however, use of

```
struct a { ... };
```

Requires you to use the following to declare variables:

```
int main ( int, char ** ) 
{
    struct a instance;
}
```

To avoid the redundant `struct` in variable declarations, use of the aforementioned `typedef` is required and allows you to use only the `a instance;` syntax

Comment: Note that the `struct a instance;` syntax is also valid in C++.  If `a` was declared as `class` instead, you could also write `class a instance;`.

Comment: é: You can also write `class a` if `a` was defined with `struct`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In the first to declare you must say `struct a my_struct;` in the latter you simply say `a my_struct;`

Comment: @delnan : You are correct, I've been doing WAY too much C recently and I think things like this have probably sneaked their way into my C++ code.